# Time series Analysis using LS

Tags: regression, time-series, trend, test-for-trend

I know this is a bit of a broad question but generally if I have a time series and I want to measure whether it has trend according to time I do the following:

I regress the series against time, time^2 and time^3 and get that only time^2 and time^3 are statistically significant whereas time is not (has a p-value of over 0.9)
but then I do the regression with only time and I find that it IS significant (p-value 0.000). So should I say that the series does have a trend based on the 2'nd result of statistical significance or say no not really based on the 1st regression.

Thanks

Comment: You should consider which of the two models is more likely to be well specified. (You may do diagnostic tests on model residuals, compare AIC or BIC values of the two models, etc.) You would like to make inference based on a well-specified model rather than a poorly specified one.

Comment: This is likely caused by using a raw coding of the polynomial. I would either recommend to sequentially test the raw polynomial terms in an ANOVA and/or use an orthogonal rather than a raw coding for the polynomial terms. For R this is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999900/poly-in-lm-difference-between-raw-vs-orthogonal/30000214#30000214

Comment: if your goal is accurate prediction, then use all the variables do not rely on statistical significance to select or infer which variables to include/exclude. If your goal is inference rely on theory/analog products to determine which variables makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Run a Dickey-Fuller test for existence of a unit root (stationarity or integration), trend or drift in your time series. There are 3 basic tests based on the null hypothesis that the unit root=0:
1. Test for a unit root
2. Test for a unit root with drift
3. Test for a unit root with drift and a deterministic time trend 
In addition, the augmented D-F test can be used for more complex time series.